# Configure dead letter queue. DLQ for a jms consumer

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms, dead-letter

It is a rather simple question... I have a spring project where I consume queues (CONSUMER).
Now I want to configure individual dead letter queues for each queue I am consuming.

However, in my mind, the individual dead letter queues configuration must be done in the broker service (SERVER), not in the CONSUMER. Is it really so?

My code below WILL NOT work, correct?

> ```
> @Bean
> public DeadLetterStrategy deadLetterStrategy(){
>     IndividualDeadLetterStrategy dlq = new IndividualDeadLetterStrategy();
>     dlq.setQueueSuffix(".DLQ");
>     dlq.setUseQueueForQueueMessages(true);
>     return dlq;
> }
>
> @Bean
> public ActiveMQConnectionFactory consumerActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
>     var activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
>     activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
>
>     RedeliveryPolicy policy = activeMQConnectionFactory.getRedeliveryPolicy();
>     policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(maximumRedeliveries);
>     policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(0);
>     policy.setBackOffMultiplier(3);
>     policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
>
>     return activeMQConnectionFactory;
> }
>
> @Bean
> public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
>     var factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
>     factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(JmsProperties.AcknowledgeMode.CLIENT.getMode());
>     factory.setConcurrency(factoryConcurrency);
>     factory.setConnectionFactory(consumerActiveMQConnectionFactory());
>
>     return factory;
> }
>
> @Bean
> public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
>     final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
>     broker.addConnector(brokerUrl);
>     broker.setPersistent(false);
>     broker.setDestinationPolicy(policyMap());
>     return broker;
> }
>
> @Bean
> public PolicyMap policyMap() {
>     PolicyMap destinationPolicy = new PolicyMap();
>     List<PolicyEntry> entries = new ArrayList<PolicyEntry>();
>     PolicyEntry queueEntry = new PolicyEntry();
>     queueEntry.setQueue(">"); // In activemq '>' does the same thing as '*' does in other languages
>     queueEntry.setDeadLetterStrategy(deadLetterStrategy());
>     entries.add(queueEntry);
>     destinationPolicy.setPolicyEntries(entries);
>     return destinationPolicy;
> } }
> ```

```
@JmsListener(destination = "myqueue")
    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
        try {
            stuff()
            message.acknowledge();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            session.recover();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: Version 5.15.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JMS consumer in ActiveMQ 5.x cannot configure the broker side dead letter strategy, this must be done at the broker in the configuration XML or via programmatic broker configuration.  You could configure it in spring as you've done if your broker is simply an in memory broker however that is of little use for most applications.

Refer to the [broker documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling) for more help on configuration of the broker.